# Exposing Next.js Environment Variables to PWA's API-Platform

Tags: reactjs, next.js, api-platform.com

According to the official documentation of Next.js, to [expose an environment variable](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) is necessary to use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix, but the admin uses [`process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT`](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/4e2dd43c54a45135afcd73300828cf5d9eb0eec7/pwa/pages/admin/index.tsx#L4).

In my case to access the `REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT` env var, I needed to substitute to `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT`. Only with this pwa can access the value.

Is that right or am I making a mistake in changing this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right partially, Next exposes env variables that has a prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_` **automatically**, if your app expects to get `REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT`, there is no point of renaming the variable, since your app won't consume it.

If I understood your scenario correctly, you need to expose `REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT`, since next doesn't do it automatically, you need to specify if manually in your `next.config.js` file.

```js
//next.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  env: {
    REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT, // assumes that your variable is defined
  }
  ...
}
```